# AlertDialog in Android 8.0 Oreo missing message text

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-8.0-oreo

I have a couple of phones, an infinix hot note 4 running Android 6.0 Marshmallow and a Nexus 6P running the latest and greatest Android 8.0 Oreo.

I'm testing an app that allows users to enter data only when they are near a particular location and I noticed that on Oreo none of my messages in AlertDialogs are shown. They appear as blank (or maybe coloured in white text or something).

I'm in Africa and i'm supporting devices running android 9 
(old phones are never thrown away just handed down and used till they expire)
so gradle settings are
minSdkVersion 9
targetSdkVersion 22
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

I've attached screenshots of both the Nexus and Infinix dialogs.
Anyone know how to go around this behaviour?  Below also is the EXACT code used in both devices

Thanks in Advance to anyone who takes the time to check out this question.

```
   private void showNotNearOutlet(ProximityToOutlet proximityToOutlet, String OutletName) {
    String strMsg = "";
    int intAllowedProximity = GSR.getSavedSettings.getAllowedProximityToOutletMeters();

    float floatDistanceFromOutlet = proximityToOutlet.getFltDistanceBetweenCurrentLocAndOutlet();
    String strDistance = String.valueOf(df.format(floatDistanceFromOutlet)) + "m";
    if (floatDistanceFromOutlet > 1000) {

        strDistance = df.format(floatDistanceFromOutlet / 1000) + "Km";
    }
    final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Cannot start outlet!");
    if (floatDistanceFromOutlet != -99) { /*means we cant get a good location fix at the moment*/
        strMsg = "GPS shows your current location as being " + strDistance + " from " + OutletName + " .\n\nYou must be at least " + intAllowedProximity + " Meters near the Outlet to start it.";
    } else {
        strMsg = "Cannot Start outlet because your current GPS position is undetermined.\nTap on 'Locate Me' button and wait till you get a GPS Fix or Accuracy is within 20meters.\n\nTo start an Outlet you must be within " + intAllowedProximity + " meters of it.";
    }


    alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(true);
    alertDialogBuilder.setIcon(R.drawable.red_gps_icon);
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(strMsg);
    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //fetchOutletsForSpinner();
            setSpinnerToSelectOutlet();
            dialog.dismiss();
        }

    });


    alertGPS = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    if (!MainActivity.this.isFinishing()) {
        //show dialog
        alertGPS.show();
        blnGPSAlertIsVisible = true;
    }


}
```

[Missing AlertDialog text in Android Oreo(left). interestingly, missing gps icon in versions before 8.0][[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5jmi.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5jmi.jpg) (Right)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`android.util.FloatMath` was deprecated in API level 22, use `java.lang.Math` for API>21 instead.

Also change compileSdkVersion 25 to 26, buildToolsVersion '25.0.0' to '26.0.2'

Comment: Thank you very much, Alexander. your suggestions worked beautifully. the Alert Dialogs now show content in Oreo. cheers.

Comment: I also found that there was an issue with my Dialog Themes where I had foreground and background setting being both white which of course caused the white text to not be visible.